# How to scale a numeric vector in 1 or 2 steps in R?

Tags: r, vector

I have a numeric vector as below:-

```
num <- c(1.2,2.3,2.4,4.6,1.43,8.99,7.12,6.77,......)
```

This vector is quite a big vector.

What I want to do is to replace all values between 1 and 2 with 1, values between 2 and 3 with 2 and so on.

```
num_scaled <- c(1,2,2,4,1,8,7,6,.....)
```

Is there any simpler way to do this in R? A function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
num <- c(1.2,2.3,2.4,4.6,1.43,8.99,7.12,6.77)
num_scaled <- trunc(num)
```

gives you:

```
> num_scaled
[1] 1 2 2 4 1 8 7 6
```

Comment: Worked. I am new to R. Didnt quite know about this function. Thanks.

Comment: What if I want to reduce the scale further, like values between 1 to 3 with 1 and values between 3 to 5 with 3 and so on? Then it trunc() wont work. Would it?

Comment: I would not know any function off the top of my head, but you could have a look at `?pmax` and `?pmin`

Comment: @user2474387 in those cases you could run a loop of the type `for( j in 1:5 ) num[num > (2*j-1) & num < (2*j+1)] <- num[j+1]`